# D2L catch LTI as parameters from a URL

Tags: php, desire2learn, valence, lti

I'm trying to send the `orgUnitId` of a course from a widget in `D2L` to a webpage (stored on the same server). The webpage is displayed in the widget via an `<iframe>`.

Example:

```
<iframe src="http://valence.newbie.edu/d2l/custom-widget/?orgunitcode={OrgUnitCode}&amp;"></iframe>
```

How can I catch the `orgunitcode` from the URL (like a parameter in a script stored on the server)?

Thanks in advance